# Display table with category name in one column and list of items belonging to category in second column with links on Details View in ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I my ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 app I have Model that stores professions which looks like this:

```
public partial class Professions
{
    public int ProfessionID { get; set; }
    public int? ProfessionGroupID { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionDescription { get; set; }
}
```

So each profession belongs to some group of professions, therefore Model for profession groups looks like this:

```
public partial class ProfessionGroups
{
    public ProfessionGroups()
    {
        Professions = new HashSet<Professions>();
    }

    public int ProfessionGroupID { get; set; }
    public int ProfessionGroupTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionGroupDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Professions> Professions { get; set; }
}
```

How can I display list of groups of professions in one columns and list of professions in another column
with links which leads to each profession `Details` View?
This is how output table in some `View` should look:

| ProfessionGroups | Professions |
| --- | --- |
| Physiotherapy | [Graduated physiotherapist](http://..) [Physiotherapist (bachelor degree)](http://...) [Physiotherapy technician](http://..) |
| Geology | [Geological technician](http://..) [Geology engineer](http://..) |

So far I've created ViewModel that suppose to hold needed data:

```
public class ProfGroupsVM
{
    public int ProfessionGroupID { get; set; }
    public string ProfessionGroupTitle { get; set; }
    public List<int> ProfIDs { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public List<string> ProfTitles { get; set; } = new List<string>();

}
```

For each `ProfessionGroupID` it has to populate `ProfIDs` with list of professions belonging to that group and `ProfTitles` should hold professions titles.

So in Controller so far I have:

```
   var profGroupsVM= new ProfGroupsVM();

   var result = from p in _context.Professions
        group p.ProfessionID by p.ProfessionGroupID into g
                select new  { ProfessionGroupID = g.Key, ProfessionIDs= g.ToList() };
```

I don't know how to assign this result back to my `ViewModel` nor how to display desired `View`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to change the `ProfGroupsVM` model to this:

```
public class ProfGroupsVM
    {
        public int ProfessionGroupID { get; set; }
        public string ProfessionGroupTitle { get; set; }
        public List<ProfInfo> Professions { get; set; }

        public class ProfInfo
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public string Title { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And to get information use this:

```
   _dbContext.ProfessionGroups.Include(x => x.Professions)
              .Select(x => new ProfGroupsVM()
              {
                  ProfessionGroupID = x.ProfessionGroupID,
                  ProfessionGroupTitle = x.ProfessionGroupTitle,
                  Professions = x.Professions.Select(p => new ProfGroupsVM.ProfInfo
                  {
                      Id = p.ProfessionID,
                      Title = p.ProfessionTitle
                  }).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

And in you view try this to show information(I'm not good in UI :)):

```
@model List<ProfGroupsVM>

 <div>
  <ul>
      @foreach (var group in Model)
      {
        <li>@group.ProfessionGroupTitle</li>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var profession in group.Professions)
            {
                <li><a href="@profession.Id">@profession.Title</a></li>
            }
        </ul>

       }
   </ul>
```

Or if you stick with your `ViewModel` for `ul` part you can put this:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var idsTitles in item.ProfIDs.Zip(@item.ProfTitles, Tuple.Create)) 
{
<li><a asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Profession" asp-route-id="@idsTitles.Item1">@idsTitles.Item2</a></li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks great, how do I pass that to my view?

Comment: I mean I do have one-to-many relationship between those tables and I have successfully applied your code to my ViewModel. Just don't know how to pass it...sorry, not really experienced with .net

Comment: You can use ``List<ProfGroupsVM>`` as ``ViewModel`` in your  ``View`` or you can you use another model that has a property ``List<ProfGroupsVM>`` and then do a loop over it to show data.

Comment: It was stupid question, got it working. I got `ModelView` working now problem is that it's displaying list of professions without separation. How do I turn `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProfTitles)` into iterator which will generate list of links on Details page of individual professions?  It could be done by using IDs of professions which is reason I have `ProfIDs` list in ViewModel. Links should look like this: /Professions/Details/ID where ID is taken from `ProfIDs` list.

Comment: @Harvey I edited the answer, I hope it helped

Comment: Your answer gave me idea so I used zip to merge IDs and Titles in View and it worked  :). I hope you don't mind I've added my option as solution to your answer. I'm sure it's better to keep things organized like you suggested.